# how to get work rerendering elements with dynamicaly id in RichFaces

Tags: jsf, richfaces, render, rerender

I have the following code on my page:

```
    <a4j:repeat value="#{tdController.cu.esaDoutCUConsigment.esaDoutCUDepartureArrivalTransport.transportMeans}" var="transportMean" rowKeyVar="idx">
              <tr>
                <td>
                    <rich:autocomplete id="transportMeansInactiveCountry#{idx}" mode="cachedAjax"
                                       autocompleteMethod="#{countryList.autoComplete}"
                                       minChars="1" layout="grid"
                                       var="country" fetchValue="#{country.code}" width="50px"
                                       inputClass="autoCompleteWidth20"
                                       immediate="true" autofill="true"
                                       value="#{transportMean.country}"
                                       converter="com.enfasis.eced.common.controller.converter.CountryConverterAutoComplete">
                        <h:outputFormat value="{0}({1})">
                            <f:param value="#{country.name}"/>
                            <f:param value="#{country.code}"/>
                        </h:outputFormat>

                        <a4j:ajax event="selectitem" execute="@this"
                                  render="transportMeansInactiveCountryCode#{idx}"/>
                    </rich:autocomplete>
                    <h:outputText id="transportMeansInactiveCountryCode#{idx}"
                                  value="#{transportMean.country.name}" style="margin-left:5px"/>
                </td>
                                    ...
   </a4j:repeat....
```

in a4j:repeat loop i'm setting id dynamically by adding row index at the end of id name like id="transportMeansInactiveCountryCode#{idx}".

But when i'm setting ids in such way, rerendering of elemnent with   id="transportMeansInactiveCountryCode#{idx}" doesn't work.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to remove the index from the ID attribute.
Its auto generated with index for you.

to check this, run your page then view the page HTML source.
you will find that the component id is like  `<form_name>-<id>-<index>`
Note: try to enclose your aj:repeat in side a